# How to build and run C++ API demos in gmsh?

Tags: compilation, mesh

I want to use gmsh C++ API to develop software.

I can build the project using cmake from source file on Ubuntu and get a executable file "gmsh".

My problem is:

1. How to compile the program as a shared library?
2. How to compile C++ API demos with the shared library and run it?

May be it is a stupid problems, but I have trapped here for hours.

Is there any step by step instructions can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, the accepted answer link is wrong! This is the [right link](https://gitlab.onelab.info/gmsh/gmsh/-/blob/master/README.txt).
When you use `cmake`，you must make sure you set `ENABLE_BUILD_DYNAMIC` to `1`.

Here are my commandline on Windows:

```
cd gmsh_source_code_dir
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DENABLE_BUILD_DYNAMIC=1 -DENABLE_FLTK=0 ..
cmake --build . --config Release
cmake --install .
```

You can find `gmsh.lib` and `gmsh.dll` in install directory. Then you can develop your software if you import lib or dll in your project.

Answer (score 0):

The detailed instructions can be found at

https://gitlab.onelab.info/gmsh/gmsh/blob/master/demos/api/README.txt